# Running forever with a --stack-size argument?

Tags: node.js, forever

I start my node app like this:

```
node --stack-size=32000 app.js
```

How can I use forever to start up my app with the appropriate --stack-size option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the `node` command in quotes with the `-c` command:

```
forever start -c "node --stack-size=32000" app.js
```